# Is this a valid copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I've just started learning about `Rule of Three` and was wondering if the following approach was sufficient for a copy constructor:

```
Array<T, ROW, COL>(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &array) {
    *this = array;
}
```

If it isn't sufficient, why not?

**EDIT** Added the assignment operator per request

```
inline Array<T, ROW, COL>& operator=(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &other) {;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j) {
            data[j*ROW + i] = other(i, j);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: So the copy-constructor uses copy-assignment for its data members? Not gord. :(

Comment: I think we'd need to see operator= to be certain.

Comment: You just call the (copy-) assignment operator, so you have to be aware that `*this` is still uninitialized (I mean, the primitive members) when calling that... Did you just call the assignment to save coding effort?

Comment: @leemes I fixed the ROW/COL mistake. Edited to include the assignment operator.

Comment: It looks like your assignment operator would leak memory if your `data` member was already initialized before.

Comment: `data` will be uninitialized when your copy constructor calls `operator =`, deleting it is undefined behavior. Also, if you aren't going to handle exceptions during the copy loop, there's no reason to get fresh memory for `data` in `operator=` instead of reusing an old block.

Comment: @Casey Good point. Since the data is initialized in the Constructors by default, I can recycle the same block. Edited.

Comment: In your current implementation, `data` in the new object is never initialized (the pointer itself) but you write to it... You need *either* `data(new T[...])` in the copy-ctor *or* as in my answer a `data(0)` in copy-ctor + `data = new T[...]` in assignment op.

Comment: Why wasn't it cool to just use `std::vector<T>` as `data` and not write the 10 iterations of half-broken operators at all?

Comment: @BalogPal Can't use std::vector<T> on CUDA, baby! Also, this type of memory can be easily mapped to a CUDA texture, which is my end goal.

Comment: Besides the issues regarding proper initialization/allocation: The other way round is more common. Doing the "copy stuff" in the copy-constructor, provide a swap function, having a by-value parameter in the assignment and do a swap. See [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom?rq=1).

Comment: @TylerJandreau: and why is that? WG21 f..d up the library with the allocators with I thought exactly this case in mind.

Comment: @BalogPal I don't know anything about WG21, I just know std::vector<> templates don't work on my CUDA card.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector the template has a second parameter where you can supply an allocator. With proper one it could work no worse than any other hand-written solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one important reason why it's not enough with the code you proposed:

- The assignment operator is applied on a **initialized object**, but this is not the case in the copy constructor. Specifically, your `data` member is not initialized properly when the code runs `*this = array` (`data` isn't in a member-initializer list), so you are calling `delete[]` operator on the uninitialized `data`.

It requires you to, at least, use a member-initializer list to initialize the `data` member before you use it.

There are more drawbacks about your propose:

- The assignment operator forces restrictions on `T` type (but maybe that restrictions are in the class `Array` anyway):

  - `T` must be default-constructible (as noted by leemes).
- assignment operator is not good implemented:

  - is not considering case `a = a` (self-assignment), as Nick Bougalis noted.
- is not exception safe:

  - if `new[]` operator fails, the object will be in an inconsistent state.
  - if copying `T` throws an exception, the object will be in an inconsistent state.

I see a much better approach with using the copy constructor in assignment operator implementation instead of the opposite:

```
Array<T, ROW, COL>(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &array): data(new T[ROW * COL]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j) {
            data[j*ROW + i] = other(i, j);
        }
    }
}

Array<T, ROW, COL>& operator=(Array<T, ROW, COL> other) {
    swap(other);
    return *this;
}

void swap(Array<T, ROW, COL>& other) {
    T* tmp = data;
    data = other.data;
    other.data = tmp;
}
```

(This is also known as the **copy-and-swap idiom**.)

Comment: Good first answer, congratulations! May I correct your English?

Comment: Done! And again, congratulations. You summarized a couple of problems very nicely.

Answer (score 4):

**General notes** (before you edited your question):

Just calling the copy assignment operator in a copy constructor is not a general solution. They mean different things (I mean, why should they be there if they meant the same).

- The **assignment operator** is called when an (existing!) object is assigned a new value. 
  If this object is of the same type, we call this also the *copy assignment*, since a typical implementation simply copies the contents (but might share some referenced things, like for example shared pointers or PIMPL classes with shared data). A copy assignment operator is implemented by the compiler automatically unless you provide one. It copies each member using the assignment operators of their types (primitive members are also copied).
- The **copy constructor** is called when a (not yet existing!) obejct is assigned an initial value of the same type, i.e. it should be initialized with the copy of an existing object. Again, if you don't provide a copy constructor, the compiler generates one for you, again just copying the members using the copy constructor.

If you call the assignment operator from within the copy constructor, this means that the generated program performs the following steps when copy-initializing a new object:

- (Unless you use member-initializer list:) It initializes non-primitive class members with default constructors. Primitive types are left uninitialized.
- Then, the assignment operator is called. If you didn't define one, it copies all members.

So it *should* be fine in most cases, but there are a couple of cases in which this does *not* work, in particular if your class has members which *can't* be default-constructed or can't be assigned. If this is the case, and if they can still be copy-constructed (in contrast to copy-assigned), you have to initialize the members in the member-initialization list of the copy constructor manually.

---

**EDIT** (Since the question got edited): In your case, `data` is a primitive type (all pointers are considered primitive), so you have to initialize it properly in the copy constructor before calling your assignment operator. If you don't do so, the assignment will delete an uninitialized pointer. So the best you should to (to avoid code duplication; it could be more efficient if you did):

```
Array<T, ROW, COL>(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &array) :
    data(0)  // Now it is at least initialized, although inefficient
{
    *this = array;
}
```

The assignment operator will then try to delete a null-pointer, which is okay (it just does nothing), and then performs the actual copy. Consider the `data(0)` initialization just as a "default-constructed null `Array<...>`" object, just temporarily. (Maybe you already provide a null-object which does *not* allocate external memory?)

Comment: What makes you think that `data` is a primitive type? It's probably of type `T`, which means it could be an array of non-primitive types.

Comment: In the OP code, there used to be `delete[] data` and `data = new T[...]`, so it obviously is of type `T*`, which is a primitive type, regardless of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent post by leemes, let me add one note of caution. In your `operator=` implementation you should consider adding a check to at least handle self-assignment (that is `a = a;`). Also, if your `data` member variable is a pointer (as your original code suggests), then you *MUST* make sure that it points to some valid memory, because if you initialize it to point to `0` in the copy-constructor your assignment operator will crash when it tries to dereference it.

```
inline Array<T, ROW, COL>& operator=(const Array<T, ROW, COL> &other) 
{
    if(this == &other)
        return *this; // nothing to do!

    /* You should make sure that either data already points to an allocated
     * buffer of the appropriate size, or you should allocate it at this point.
     */

    assert(data != NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j) {
            data[j*ROW + i] = other(i, j);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Good catch. Self-assignment is often forgotten ;)